# Can we integrate some third party ios sdk/API part of hybrid application created using worklight?

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst

I am very new to mobile worklight development.

I want to know whether a third party iOS SDK/API can be integrated part of the hybrid application created using worklight.

If so how can we access the methods in that API part of the javascript?

Please help me in finding this.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about JavaScript-based libraries, then all you need to do is include any JS and/or CSS files that library comes with in your project, and reference these files in the HTML like you would do in a regular website (you reference them in the HEAD element).

For example,

1. In Eclipse, create a new folder, "my-library", under `my-project-name\apps\my-app-name\common\`
2. In your HTML file (located in `my-project-name\apps\my-app-name\common\index.html`) you simply reference the .js files

   > ```
   > <head>
   >     ...
   >     ...
   >     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
   >     <script src="my-library/library.js"></script>
   > </head>
   > ```

Typically libraries come with instructions...

---

If you are talking about native iOS libraries, then this is not related to Worklight.

After you generate the Xcode project using Worklight Studio, you proceed as if it were any other iOS application and add libraries to your project using the tools, procedures and guidelines provided by Apple.

See the following Apple documentation:

- [Linking to a Library or Framework in Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/AddingaLibrarytoaTarget.html)